# Interlinking 2 scaffolds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am having a problem with some understanding of inter-connection with 2 scaffolds.

I have made one scaffold and used an external xml file to parse the data (nokogiri) and then i have placed that data in a scaffold to auto generate each page for the different items i have (there are only about 50 items).

I have another file with things that are meant to go inside each of those files but they are all stored in 1 xml file. But they are alphabetized so the top one will always remain the top and the bottom one will always remain at the bottom.

Parsing the data will be fine but how would the inter connection go??

Answer (score 0):

This is a very abstract question (without any models and such). So a very abstract reply.

- First you import the 50 items into your scaffolded model. Those 50 items will get new ids.
- When trying to import the related items, you will need to find the correct parent-item. Using the ID will not work anymore. So then I see two options:

  - in a first pass you will have to change your second XML and make sure it can use another unique field (e.g. a name) to find the parent model again
  - OR you add a new field to your first model, call that something like `original_id` and use that to build the relation correctly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the model element to interlinks scaffolds together. You would need a primary and foreign key to be able to conduct that.

```
  has_many :screenings
  has_many :films, :through => :screenings
  has_one :location
```